# Android Chrome Data Saver causing website issues

Tags: php, android, .htaccess, google-chrome

We recently developed a website and deployed to live. Only for Android phones, in the Chrome Browser with Data Saver turned on (which is the default setting), the website is facing a lot of issues.

One of the issues was that the user is not getting logged in after registration. Ideally, the user should be immediately logged in after registering on the website. But, with Data Saver on, after register, the user is still logged out and you have to manually login again. Could it be because the cookie is not getting created or not being persisted?

Another issue was that the JavaScript is randomly breaking on one of the pages. It behaves very weird.

I tried setting the header Cache-Control "no-transform" through htaccess but still the problem persists:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-transform"
</IfModule>
```

Any suggestions regarding this issue?

Comment: Have you seen this bug report https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=573502

Comment: @MorrisonChang The main issue with that seems to be the switching between HTTP and HTTPS. There is no such switching in my website. It's only http.

Comment: i'm also facing this issue in many of my websites for android mobile users.

Answer (score -3):

I'm the lead on the Data Saver team. This should not be happening - if you can share details of the site (URL etc.) we can look into it.

Comment: I have troubles login in on some sites, I seem to have Google IP's when I try to login. Then I disable the Data Saver and I can normally log in to pages. They are on http not https. Is there a way for the developers to tell the client not to cache login pages?

Comment: @littleibex Winwithca.com seems to be working fine with Data Saver; can you confirm?

Comment: @Rumplin Can you give me an example of the sites you are having problems with?

Comment: @mdwelsh yes, but not public, I can give it to you in private. The problem is with reCaptcha pages. Because when you submit the form, the IP is validated on the submited page, and it's IP from Google, not the clients.

Comment: @Rumplin Please send me email at mdw at google dot com or PM me on Stack Exchange. Thanks!